# About CGColor/definition

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgcolor

In a class I have a variable myColor of type CGColorRef declared as follow:

```
@implementation MyClass
{
    .......
    CGColorRef myColor;
    .......
```

Here are two lines of Objective C code:

First line:

```
myColor=[UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
```

Second line:

```
myColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:1.000 green:0.500 blue:0.000 alpha:1.000].CGColor;
```

I first expected them to be equivalent, but they are not.

I know they are not equivalent, because when I use the first one my program works. And when I use the second one it crashes later down the road. Showing more code here would be totally irrelevant to the question.

Can someone explain the difference? That will hopefully allow me to modify my code and be able to use the second line.

Just for reference, it crashes in (with: *Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x881b370e0)*):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    .......
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,myColor); // Crash here !!!
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
    .......
}
```

Comment: The point is not the code that crashes. Since I have clearly proven that the two lines of code mentioned are not equivalent, the point is to know what makes the difference between the two lines.

Comment: Right, I don't know the answer; but I know the question (when I write "the point is", I am referring to the question). If you read the post you will see that there is no question about the "crash" (the word is only used to prove that the 2 lines are not equivalent). The question is about the difference between the two lines. But to make you happy I will modify my post to say where it crashes.

Comment: @Michel Could you please show us How you declare the color property. If possible put full class code of your UIView

Comment: @Prashant Tukadiya. I have just edited my post to show the declaration of myColor.

Comment: @Michel OK, so memory management of CFTypeRefs is covered in my book here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_memory_management_of_cftyperefs Memory management of instance properties without ARC is discussed here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_memory_management_of_instance_variables_non_arc And a CFTypeRef _is_ without ARC. Because of this, memory-managing a CFTypeRef instance property is incredibly difficult and not worth the trouble; it's better to wrap it in a Cocoa object type, and that is exactly what the accepted answer advises you to do.

Comment: (Note that you would not have this problem if you were using Swift, because CFTypeRefs _are_ ARC-managed in Swift. That's why I didn't spot the issue at once; I've been using Swift since its initial release, so my mind had blocked out the preceding years of horror of CFType memory management in Objective-C.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crash is because may be you don't have strong ref (property) of `myColor` object. You might has `assign` property

### Reason why `[UIColor orangeColor]` works but not  `[UIColor colorWithRed...`

When you use [UIColor orangeColor], you don't create the object; you get a reference to it and something else manages its life cycle.

When you init a new `UIColor` object, you're responsible for making sure it is still valid when used. "**assign**" doesn't increase the object's reference count; "**strong**" does.

Hope it is helpful

**EDIT**

Decleare the one  property like this

`@property (nonatomic,strong)  UIColor * myUIColor;`

Now When you can

do this like

`myUIColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:1.000 green:0.500 blue:0.000 alpha:1.000]`

when you need CGColor

`myUIColor. CGColor`

Comment: I see the point, but myColor is not just a local variable. It is an instance variable, so there is no reason why it would get lost.

Comment: @Michel Add the code how you declare it. You must declare it as `@property`   with strong

Comment: Yes, I have tried your suggestion and it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Michel Glad that solution work for you, Happy to help :)

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning to an instance variable of Core Foundation type `CGColorRef`. That type is not an ObjC object type, so is not subject to ARC (automatic memory management), which means you need to manage its memory manually.

Both of your examples are actually incorrect, but the reason you don't see the crash initially when you assign `[UIColor orangeColor].CGColor` is because of a lucky coincidence: the orange color object is probably a long-lived singleton object, and its internal `CGColor` reference is thus also long-lived, so your assignment to ivar works and later access happens to work-- but this is just a red (orange?) herring.

You *do* see a crash in the other case because the `UIColor` object that you create in passing ends up being immediately deallocated because it's not used again. Thus the `CGColorRef` value that you pull from it and assign to your ivar is is also immediately invalid and radioactive when you try to use it later.

To store a `CGColorRef` safely in your object, you need to have ownership of it, which in your case means explicitly retaining the `CGColorRef` you get from `UIColor`:

```
myColor = CGColorRetain([UIColor colorWithRed:1.000 green:0.500 blue:0.000 alpha:1.000].CGColor);
```

Or even better would be to bypass `UIColor` altogether, and just use the function that directly gives you a color ref with create ownership semantics:

```
myColor = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0);
```

In either case, you now "own" this reference, which means it's safe to use later, and also means you're responsible for cleaning it up when you're done, e.g.:

```
- (void)dealloc 
{
    CGColorRelease(myColor);
}
```

See also [this Apple Tech Q&A doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1565/_index.html) that goes into almost this same example.

---

The form of memory management required with Core Foundation objects (`CGColorRef` is one of them) is very similar to the older, pre-ARC ObjC manual system, where you increment a retain count at the point where you wish to hold ("own") the reference, and then decrement (release) when you no longer need it to be valid. Apple [has good docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-CJBEJBHH) for how to best think about this. In this case, assigning the reference to your instance variable means you want to keep it around as valid for some amount of time. Generally you retain at the point of assignment (either explicitly or by getting the reference via a [Create function](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029)), and then you'd release it when the object is deallocated.

Comment: Yes indeed this also works. I must check if I need to care about the number of CGColorRetain calls matching the number of CGColorRelease calls.

Comment: @Michel: Yes, you do, in the sense that you must balance the ownership. Note that many functions also start with `...Create...` (or `Copy`) in their name, and are equivalent to a retain (+1) so they expect a release (-1) to match. You can also explicitly retain. Here's the Apple doc that covers the ownership policies https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-CJBEJBHH

Comment: I see, that reminds me of old Objective C memory management days :) ... Is there a simple way to see if CGColorRetain has been called (other than keeping my own records)?

Comment: @Michel: It's very similar to the old ObjC rules! And just like old ObjC, you're not supposed to be asking about retain count-- as long as you follow the pattern, it will work. When you stash a reference for later use, as in your instance variable, call retain *at the point of saving* and then call release when you know you are done and won't use that saved reference anymore (ie, dealloc). The wrinkle is that you'll rarely call the "retain" explicitly-- you're almost always going to obtain a reference in the first place via a `Create..` function--which implies the retain for you.

Comment: Yeah, I solved it. When in dealloc I still need to know if I need to call CGColorRelease or not. But that's no big issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Michel: Think about it this way: you should retain the reference for the life of the instance variable's validity. Thus you retain it (+1) when you assign to the instance variable (unless it's already coming to you +1 from e.g. `CGColorCreateGenericRGB`), and you release it (-1) when the instance variable will no longer be used, i.e. in the `dealloc`. It will be "owned" by you and can be used freely for the duration between. No problem, good luck.